# Allocate memory for 2D array with C++ new[]

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, multidimensional-array

When I read some values from the user and I need to create an array of the specific size I do it somehow like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;    
unsigned* numbers;
int main()
{
int a;
cin >> a;
numbers = new unsigned[a];
}
```

How can I do it with a 2d array(sized a*b read from the user)?

Comment: But why? **whyyy?** (hint : std::vector) also, 2d arrays are evil.

Comment: vector is also good for me but don't know how to make 2d of them `vector<vector<unsigned>>` ???

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz , your comment is unconstructive for a beginner.

gen , vectors of vectors are possible, but have associated performance penalties (which I won't bother to get into here)

Comment: How so, @brennan? How is it unconstructive to suggest the only sensible solution?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz because it's not unreasonable to think that wherever he is learning C++ from thought it was worth teaching him  the core language (what arrays and pointers are) before going into the standard library. A teaching strategy you may or may not agree with, but certainly a legitimate one. Simply telling him he's wrong with a "hint" that would seem very cryptic to someone who hasn't seen the C++ standard library is unhelpful. As is saying something is "evil" with no explanation.

Comment: @Brennan Wrong, wrong, wrong. Who upvoted that comment? The standard library **is** the core language, and is far more fundamental than C-style arrays and pointers, *especially* in C++11 (but even before that). As teaching strategies go, yours is abysmal and counter-productive. Bartek’s advice is spot-on.

Comment: @BrennanVincent I'd disagree with the sentence stating "arrays and pointers are core of the C++ language". They are core of C subset, but they aren't required to write good C++ code at all. And oh, Konrad was a bit faster.

Comment: @All of you The core language is not important for me at all, just please tell me how would you store an N*M table in C++? It could me std, core, not-core, anything but please tell me :).

Comment: @gen There are already 8 answers below, including mine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anything that would look like a 2D-Array in code will not be a physical 2D array in memory, but either one plain block of memory or scattered, depending on how you allocate it.

- You can torture yourself by doing dynamic allocation of N arrays in another dynamic array of N pointers, like nrussel's answer suggests.
- You can make a vector of vectors instead, like billz and Arun C.B suggest - that would relieve you from managing the allocated memory yourself but still leave you with N+1 scattered allocations which is not very performant.
- Brennan Vincent's answer suggests allocation of one dynamic array, containing a*b elements, which gives you one continuous block in memory. Combine that with the builtin dynamic memory management of `std::vector` he mentioned and be happy:

  `std::vector<unsigned> matrix(a*b);`

If you want the matrix to be convenient to access, wrap the whole thing into a class providing you access to the elements with 2D-coordinates. But please step away from managing the memory yourself. It just hurts you and anyone who has to maintain that code (and search for mem leaks).

Comment: This is the best answer so far, IMO. Gives (arguably) the correct answer, explains why it's (arguably) correct, and avoids condescension.

Comment: tbh, I overlooked your note about std::vector, so it's just the answer you gave him, with a few additional explanations.

Comment: Well, using answers to make even better answers is the soul of stackexchange :) what's that Newton said about standing on the shoulders of giants...

Answer (score 7):

If a and b are the number of rows and number of columns, respectively, you may allocate the array like this:

```
new unsigned[a * b];
```

To access the element at row `i` and column `j`, do this:

```
numbers[i * b + j]
```

However, note that in reality you're almost certainly better off using `std::vector` for whatever you're trying to do, but you may not have learned about that yet :)

Comment: I know a bit about vectors, are there any "tricky" things about them that I should know?

Comment: You might be interested in the `reserve(n)` function on vectors. It makes sure the vector has enough memory allocated to hold whatever you are trying to store in it.


Edit: It's not formally necessary. If you don't call it, the vector will handle reallocating new memory and copying over its contents to the new memory whenever it runs out of memory. So the behavior is the same with or without `reserve`. But you may want to call `reserve` to avoid all this recopying, for performance reasons.

Answer (score 3):

Could just use one vector to represent two dimension arrays:

```
   typedef std::vector<int>     d1_type;       // 1D
   typedef std::vector<d1_type> d2_type;       // 2D
   typedef std::vector<d2_type> d3_type;       // 3D


   int num = 5;
   d2_type value2d(num, d1_type(num));
   d3_type value3d(num, d2_type(num, d1_type(num)));
```

And you can access 2D/3D vector like array, for example:

```
 value2d[0][0] = 100;
 value3d[0][0][0] = 100;
```

Comment: Be worth mentioning alternative constructors that would permit construction of the `vector` with specific dimensions.

Comment: If your array isn't jagged (each row has the same number of entries) then you don't need to do this, you can just allocate everything within one vector, as I proposed in my answer. Then you can reserve the space you need all at once.

Comment: sorry @hmjd, more specific?

Comment: See [vector constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector). There is a constructor that permits a `vector` to be constructed containing a specific number of elements.

Comment: IF I want this 2d vector to be global, than at reading the values into the vector goes like this: `for(i) {numbers.push_back(); for(j) {cin >> a; numbers[i].push_back(a);}}` ??

Comment: This isnt 2D but a sparse matrix.

Comment: @gen use typedef and vector contstructor is much easier, see my pdated answer

Answer (score 3):

### Updated recommendation:

It's worth noting that [**boost already did that.**](http://www.boost.org/libs/multi_array/) So I'll just stick to it, if it isn't meant to be encapsulated in a class.

### Original answer:

In general, using raw arrays and allocations is inferior to using `std::vector`. Now, you can of course use `vector<vector<T>>`, but that's not only lenghty to type, but can also involve unnecessary copying.

Using `ptr_vector` or `vector<unique_ptr<vector<int>>` would solve the second problem, but complicate the matters even worse. So how to solve it?

It's simple: **Don't use 2D arrays at all**.

Imagine your 2D array in memory:

```
[X|X|X|X]
[Y|Y|Y|Y]
[Z|Z|Z|Z]
```

It's obvious enough that it could be put in one row:

```
[X|X|X|X|Y|Y|Y|Y|Z|Z|Z|Z]
```

Now we're back to old, familiar 1D array (doesn't matter if it's a `vector` or C-style array). In order to get to your element, you have to know the width of your initial array, and go to the array element corresponding to n'th row, then plainly add the number of columns:

```
int& access (unsigned x, unsigned y) { 
    return data[x * sizeY + y]; // Or (y * sizeX + x)
}
```

Since it's a stub method, you might have a problem in actual usage. Here's an example of a global implementation:

```
int& accessVectorAs2d (std::vector<int> & data, unsigned x, unsigned y, unsigned int sizeY); // inside stays the same
unsigned SizeX = 20, SizeY = 20;
std::vector<int> V (SizeX * SizeY, 0);

accessVectorAs2d(V, 1, 3, SizeX) = 5;
```

Reference is returned to allow using your 1D structure in a very similar way to normal 2D array:

```
// So you can do either reads
int X = access(1, 3);

// Or writes!
access(1,3) = 5;
```

Additional note: if you'll construct your own class, overloading `operator()` can give you even better results:

```
Data(1, 3) = 5;
int X = Data(1, 3);
```

Now how you're gonna implement that access (subclassing or encapsulating vector, or just using plain global function) doesn't really matter.

I'd strongly suggest you used `std::vector` here. It will ensure no memory will leak (forgotten delete), it will be easier to change the size (either by `.push_back()` or `.reserve()`) and is in general suggested practice; you're writing in C++, not in C, after all.

### Behold! Dragons after this point!

Actually the class should of course be templated, with not only the type, but also number of dimensions (okay, that can be simplified) and size of (every-1) dimension (-1 to allow unlimited growth in one side). This would be probably done best by creating appropriate access functions at compile time, calculating

Sum<sub>i = 0</sub><sup>i < n</sup> (Size<sub>i</sub>)<sup>i</sup> * D<sub>i</sub>,

where n is number of dimensions, S is an array of dimension sizes, and D is an array of coordinates.

Comment: Good answer, I upvoted. Question: why return a reference from `access` ?

Comment: I've added an explanation.

Comment: You cannot overload `operator[]` with multiple arguments, you need to use `operator()` instead.

Comment: +1 for the effort, but two annotations: to use the array "look-and-feel", one could provide a inner class Row, making something like `Data[3][5]` possible. Just a nice-to-have, but not necessary to deal with the 2D. The other thing I'd like to mention: **DON'T** subclass vector. It's not designed to be a base class leading to splicing and similar kind of errors if you derive from it without using the derived class very carefully. There is no reason to choose subclassing over encapsulation ("too lazy to write the forwarding methods" doesn't count as a reason).

Comment: thanks @Arne, your input is very valuable. I also prefer encapsulating vector, because usually access to it should be made from a classanyway, and then a simple inline private method is just enough.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use vectors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
// An empty vector of vectors. The space 
// between the 2 '>' signs is necessary
vector<vector<int> > v2d;

// If you intend creating many vectors 
// of vectors, the following's tidier
  typedef vector<vector<int> > IntMatrix;
  IntMatrix m;

// Now we'll try to create a 3 by 5 "matrix".
// First, create a vector with 5 elements
   vector<int> v2(5, 99); 

// Now create a vector of 3 elements. 
 // Each element is a copy of v2
 vector<vector<int> > v2d2(3,v2);

// Print out the elements
 for(int i=0;i<v2d2.size(); i++) {
  for (int j=0;j<v2d2[i].size(); j++)
    cout << v2d2[i][j] << " "; 
    cout << endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: Nitpick: The space between the two `>` is no longer necessary as of the most recent C++ standard.

Comment: @Brennan Vincent It is a new info for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can allocate the memory by using c++ new[] the following way :

```
int** array = new int*[x];
for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    aryay[i] = new int[y];
```

The simple concept of this is that its and array of pointers which are pointing to arrays. It must be deleted too to avoid the memory leaks.

Comment: I'll copy my previous comment : What if he asked for a 3d array? Or 4d?

Comment: @Bartek To be fair, 2D is a special case that crops up **vastly** more often than higher dimensions.

Comment: secondly question has been asked for 2D array .

Answer (score 1):

Although the "vector of vectors" solution can be satisfying, they are not a 2D structure: each "row" will be allocated independently of another, and length can be different row by raw (and hence the 2D constrain must be maintained manually: inserting an item requires all rows to be enlarged so that elemets that are one above the other maintain their relative position.

In case you need a proper dynamic 2D structure, you can wrap a vector (simple mono-dimensional) in a class (let's call it "`table`") and provide that class with the operation requird to properly maintain it as an externally represented 2D. In particular:

- Define a `Colums() const` and `Rows() const` functions retuning theactual size of the table.
- Define a `int& operator()(unsigned row, unsigned col) { return vect[row*Colums()+col]; }` and it s const counterpart
- Define a `struct coord { unsigned r, unsigned c }` and a convenient `table::operator[](const coord&)`
- Define `insert` and `remove` methods to insert a row (just insert `Colums()` consecutive elements at `r*Columns()`) and a column (insert one element every `Columns()+1` starting from `c`)
- Define proper iterator classes that walk along colums (++ advance by 1 element) and rows (++ advance by Colums() elements) (Beware to consitently define an `end()` value for them)

The key point of all this stuff is the understanding of the `n = r*C+c`formula at the second point. Everything else is just an almost immediate consequence.

Comment: Nice. I'd however change `T&` to `int&`, just for simplicity's sake.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: yup! I just implicitly supposed it was a template... Given the context, I update as suggested!

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned **numbers;
numbers = new unsigned*[a];
for (int i=0; i<a; i++){
    numbers[i] = new unsigned[b];
}
```

It doesn't behave exactly like a 2d array, in that it's not contiguous in memory, but it will do. You can also use the notation `numbers[i][j]` to access elements.

Remember to `delete[]` each element of `numbers` at the end before `delete[]`-ing `numbers` itself

Using `std::vector` is probably a preferable solution, as detailed in other posts

Comment: What if he asked for a 3d array? Or 4d?

Comment: He didn't. I offered a solution to the problem. But I do take your point, it doesn't generalise well.