# How to store constant 2D array in C++ class with virtual access?

Tags: c++, arrays, polymorphism, constants, virtual

I have to put few megabytes of data in two-dimensional arrays in C++ code (embed it in DLL), diffrent datasets for each subclass. I defined virtual accessor methods to access constants to specified subclass but it works only for primitives and 1D arrays, not for 2D arrays:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class SubClassHoldingData { // inheritance removed for short,compilable example
public:
    static int const notWorkingData[2][2];

    virtual int const** getNotWorkingData() { return (int const**)notWorkingData; } 
};

// simplified data set, about 200x200 in real application
const int SubClassHoldingData::notWorkingData[2][2] =  { { 1 , 2 } , { 3, 4 } };

int main( int argc , char** argv ) {
    SubClassHoldingData* holder = new SubClassHoldingData();
    const int** data = holder->getNotWorkingData();
    printf("data: %d" , data[1][1]); // !!! CRASHES APPLICATION !!!
}
```

I want to access data dynamiccaly (virtual) but with compile-time constant array like this:

```
DataHolder* holder = new FirstDataSetHolder();
const int** data = holder->get2DArray();

DataHolder* holder = new SecondDataSetHolder();
const int** data = holder->get2DArray(); 
// "data" contents DIFFERENT now, but compile-time constants!
```

How to achieve that?

Comment: Everything would be way easier if you used `std::array`.

Comment: Will it be a compile time constant, or can be loaded at application startup from constants and hold for rest of application life? Can you post a example?

Comment: looks a lot like you are doing "C with classes". `<stdio.h>` is not part of C++, the corresponding legacy header is `<cstdio>`, then you can (and should) use `std::array` or `std::vector` instead of the multidimensional arrays. For that matter, maybe [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14275773/allocate-memory-for-2d-array-with-c-new/) will be of help for you. And last but not least, [`new` is pretty old now](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-new-be-used-as-little-as-possible).

Comment: But remeber that I want to compile-time constants. I prefer loading 10MB DLL with compile-time constants rather than loading 10MB DLL with compile-time constants for initialise another dynamically allocated 10MB (20MB memory usage for 10MB of real data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the issue right, your problem is actually "how to return a pointer to pointer to some data that is in a 2D array".

The problem with two layer pointers and 2D arrays is that a 2D array doesn't automatically make a pointer to pointer - they are two different things. A 2D array `T arr[Y][X];` is a lump of memory of Y * X elements, where the offset to `arr[a][b]` is calculated as `a * X + b`.

If we use the same `arr[Y][X]` in a dynamically allocated scenario, we would allocate a lump of memory `Y` long, and populate that with pointers to `T` that to a lump of memory `X` long each. So when we want to find `arr[a][b]`, we first dig out pointer `arr[a]`, then using that pointer add `b` elements to that.

For your code to work, you would have to build that first array of pointers to each row in your array. Or return a pointer to an array with a fixed size for the `[X]` dimension, e.g.

Edited:

```
 typedef int arr[X];
 ...
 class SomethingHolder 
 {
    ...
    arr* get2DArray();
    ...
 };

 const arr* data = holder->get2DArray();
```

[I think it's technically possible to declare a function as returning a pointer to an array of integers, but I clearly didn't get the syntax right from my "obvious" type, and when trying to figure it out, I still couldn't get it right, so I gave up and used typedef of arr].

Note that X must be a compile-time constant that is the same for the whole range.

Another option is of course to have a `holder->getData(x, y)` that returns the actual data at `[y][x]` (or `[x][y]` depending on which way makes most sense).

Comment: This solution looks good, I know all dimensions before compilation. But this doesn't compile: `const int(*)[2] data = holder->getNotWorkingData();`

Comment: Even `const int[2][2] data` dosen't compile: "expected unqualified-id before '[' token"

Comment: Ok thanks, this solution works. This is a little bit problematic to create multiple typedefs for all my sizes, but i will post another question.

Comment: You may be able to use templates or something for that - or, like I said, use a `getData(x, y)` type function - if the code is written correctly, this can be inlined and fetch the correct data as quickly as anything else.

Comment: I'd use the `typedef` too, but if I'm not mistaken, the declarations without the `typedef` would be `int (*get2DArray() const)[2];` (with definition `int (*SomethingHolder::get2DArray() const)[2] { ... }`) and use `int const (*data)[2] = holder->get2DArray();`.  Which is, I think, a very strong argument in favor of the `typedef`.

Comment: Thanks James, I probably wouldn't have come up with that syntax in a 100 hours, had I had enough motivation to spend that long...

Answer (score 0):

Mats Petersson 's resolution is quite right.But if You want to use the array form.It's also have a method:

```
class SubClassHoldingData { // inheritance removed for short,compilable example
public:
    static int const notWorkingData[2][2];

    virtual int const** getNotWorkingData() { return (int const**)notWorkingData; } 
};

typedef int  (*SecondDemPtr)[2][2] ;  //this type is a pointer to your array
```

And:

```
SubClassHoldingData* holder = new SubClassHoldingData();
SecondDemPtr data = (SecondDemPtr)(holder->getNotWorkingData());
printf("data: %d" , (*data)[1][1]); // !!! CRASHES APPLICATION !!!
```

This method is not a good idear,but can transform between array and pointer of array.